# Sufficient condition for solvability of linear diophantine system

Tags: diophantine-equations, integer-programming

I would like to know under what conditions does an integer solution exist to the under-determined linear system:

Ax = b. (without constraints)

Where A is m x n matrix with positive integers entries (m < n) and b is a positive integer vector.

I'm not interested in finding any solution, i would only to know if there is a fast algorithm that tells if an integer solution exists (with fast i mean faster than calculating the Hermite normal form or Smith normal form that allow to find the solution of the system).

I have found some methods based on the g.c.d. of the determinants of the mxm subsquare matricies of A but i think that they are too computational expensive (m=50 , n=100 means 100!/(50!*50!) number of mxm subsquare matricies).

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This can certainly be done in polynomial time using the
[Smith
normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form#Algorithm) (SNF) of $A$, which is a diagonal matrix $D = SAT$ for some
integer matrices $S,T$ of determinant $\pm 1$ (and thus whose inverses
$S^{-1}, T^{-1}$ also have integer entries).  Once we've computed
$S$ and $T$, and thus $D$, we have $Ax=b$ **iff**
$D(T^{-1}x) = (SAT)(T^{-1}x) = SAx = Sb$.  So there's a solution
**iff** each entry of $Sb$ is a multiple of the corresponding diagonal entry of $D$.
While polynomial-time, this technique is still cumbersome for 
your values $(m,n)=(50,100)$, but GP-Pari's **matsolvemod** 
(which includes $Ax=b$ as the special case $D=0$) 
still solves such equations routinely (assuming $A$ and $b$
have reasonably-sized entries); I'm told that it uses not
the generic SNF algorithm but a nontrivial improvement 
involving the LLL algorithm for lattice basis reduction.

Comment: I see now that the OP explicitly asked for something faster than computing the SNF.  But GP-Pari also has an efficient implementation of that (**matsnf**).  The documentation for **matsnf** and **matsolvemod** may give pointers to the algorithms.  In any case, efficient computation of SNF and $Ax=b$ is not as trivial as one might expect from experience with small matrices, because the natural recursive techniques can build up huge intermediate results.